# Best way to implement Dynamic CSS in .NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to have 2 different themes (basically 2 different **CSS**). User has an option to choose either light or dark theme. If he chooses the light theme, I need to load the light themed **CSS** and if he chooses the dark theme, I need to load the dark themed **CSS**.

I tried this

[.NET MVC: How to implement different page appearance per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020744/net-mvc-how-to-implement-different-page-appearance-per-user)

but was not able to make it working because `Url.Action` was just generating the link and it was not returning the result from the Action method.

I have a layout page which all the pages in my website inherits and I somehow want to have this to be loaded in the Layout page.

The other approach is 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1892421.aspx?Dynamic+Themes+in+MVC+Razor

Is it ok to set the **css** in `HttpContext.Application["Theme"]`?

The other approach I came across was setting the css file using javascript while loading the page.

Which approach do you think is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following way inside the layout page.
Perhaps I would/could improve the "GetThemeName" method so that it returns the full link string. So that the layout page only contains layout features instead of code.

ex:

```
@switch (UserSettings.GetThemeName())
    {
        case "Red":
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/ThemeRed/css/default.css" />
            break;
        case "Blue":
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/ThemeBlue/css/default.css" />
            break;
        default:
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Default/css/default.css" />
            break;
    }
```

the UserSettings.GetThemeName is a public static function which gets the users current "theme name" or "theme id"

Comment: Thanks Ronald. your answer generated few ideas and I have implemented it. So basically what I did was very simple  @{ string stylepathname = @Html.Action("action","controller"} and then use stylepathname in css like <link href="@stylepathname" rel="stylesheet">