# What's the best way to set a page color theme in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set up some different CSS so the user can choose between different color themes. But how can I set the theme and have it remembered from page to page for the user? Is there a best practices way to do this with MVC3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link

http://pietschsoft.com/?tag=/mvc

[Asp.Net MVC Themes, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769878/asp-net-mvc-themes-how-to)

Applying themes in MVC is a little different and you need to implement quite a bit of code but the post will let me know what exactly you need to do.